# How can I click tabs in a html-css file that was sent with Thunderbird as an attachment without using JS code?

Tags: html, css, email, tabs, thunderbird

I'm trying to send a html-css report (as an attachement) with Mozilla Thunderbird email client. The option 'Display Attachements Inline' is checked so we can see the rendered content of the .html report without downloading the file.

I'm trying to use tabs in this report file and I found this beautiful tabs here: https://codepen.io/iprodev/full/yygvPx/

The problem that I have is that when I send the html-css file with Thunderbird, when the content of the .html file is rendered in the email, I can see the tabs exactly like they are but I can't click on them / can't switch from one to another.

I looked at the code and I saw there is some JavaScript code that is responsible for click event and I know Thunderbird dosen't allow JS code to be run (security reasons i guess), so i need a way to click the tabs using only html & css.

```
<head>
    <title>Modern Tabs Design with pure CSS</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400);

        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background: #E8ECEF;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
        }
        h1{
            font: 400 30px roboto, "Open Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
        h2{
            font: 300 22px roboto, "Open Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
        .switcher-box {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 40px 0;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .switcher-box a {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 32px;
            height: 32px;
            margin-right: 10px;
            padding: 3px;
            cursor: pointer;
            background: #FFF;

            -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
                    border-radius: 50%;

            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
                    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
        }
        .switcher-box a span {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;

            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset, 0 5px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) inset;
                    box-shadow: 0 -5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset, 0 5px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) inset;

            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
               -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                    box-sizing: border-box;

            -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
                    border-radius: 50%;
        }
        .switcher-box a.active {
            background: #000;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
                    box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
        }
        .switcher-box a.active span {
            border-color: #BBB;
        }

        .switcher-box a.skin-turquoise span {
            background: #1ABC9C;
        }
        .switcher-box a.skin-emerald span {
            background: #2ECC71;
        }
        .switcher-box a.skin-peter-river span {
            background: #3498DB;
        }
        .switcher-box a.skin-amethyst span {
            background: #9B59B6;
        }
        .switcher-box a.skin-wet-asphalt span {
            background: #34495E;
        }
        .switcher-box a.skin-sun-flower span {
            background: #F1C40F;
        }
        .switcher-box a.skin-carrot span {
            background: #E67E22;
        }
        .switcher-box a.skin-alizarin span {
            background: #E74C3C;
        }
        .switcher-box a.skin-graphite span {
            background: #454545;
        }
        .switcher-box a.skin-concrete span {
            background: #95A5A6;
        }
        .switcher-box a.skin-green-sea span {
            background: #16A085;
        }
        .switcher-box a.skin-nephritis span {
            background: #27AE60;
        }
        .switcher-box a.skin-belize-hole span {
            background: #2980B9;
        }
        .switcher-box a.skin-wisteria span {
            background: #8E44AD;
        }
        .switcher-box a.skin-midnight-blue span {
            background: #2C3E50;
        }
        .switcher-box a.skin-orange span {
            background: #F39C12;
        }
        .switcher-box a.skin-pumpkin span {
            background: #D35400;
        }
        .switcher-box a.skin-pomegranate span {
            background: #C0392B;
        }
        .switcher-box a.skin-silver span {
            background: #BDC3C7;
        }
        .switcher-box a.skin-asbestos span {
            background: #7F8C8D;
        }
        .switcher-box a.skin-dodgerblue span {
            background: dodgerblue;
        }
        .switcher-box a.skin-gray-black span {
            background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
        }
        .switcher-box a.skin-black-glass span {
            background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
        }


        /* Tabbed Styles */
        .tabbed {
            width: 80%;
            min-width: 400px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            margin-bottom: 68px;
            border-bottom: 4px solid #000;
            overflow: hidden;
            transition: border 250ms ease;
        }
        .tabbed ul {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            overflow: hidden;
            float: left;
            padding-left: 48px;
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        .tabbed ul * {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        .tabbed ul li {
            display: block;
            float: right;
            padding: 10px 24px 8px;
            background-color: #FFF;
            margin-right: 46px;
            z-index: 2;
            position: relative;
            cursor: pointer;
            color: #777;

            text-transform: uppercase;
            font: 600 13px/20px roboto, "Open Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif;

            transition: all 250ms ease;
        }
        .tabbed ul li:before,
        .tabbed ul li:after {
            display: block;
            content: " ";
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            height: 100%;
            width: 44px;    
            background-color: #FFF;
            transition: all 250ms ease;
        }
        .tabbed ul li:before {
            right: -24px;
            transform: skew(30deg, 0deg);
            box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.1) 3px 2px 5px, inset rgba(255,255,255,.09) -1px 0;
        }
        .tabbed ul li:after {
            left: -24px;
            transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
            box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.1) -3px 2px 5px, inset rgba(255,255,255,.09) 1px 0;
        }
        .tabbed ul li:hover,
        .tabbed ul li:hover:before,
        .tabbed ul li:hover:after {
            background-color: #F4F7F9;
            color: #444;
        }
        .tabbed ul li.active {
            z-index: 3;
        }
        .tabbed ul li.active,
        .tabbed ul li.active:before,
        .tabbed ul li.active:after {
            background-color: #000;
            color: #fff;
        }

        /* Round Tabs */
        .tabbed.round ul li {
            border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
        }
        .tabbed.round ul li:before {
            border-radius: 0 8px 0 0;
        }
        .tabbed.round ul li:after {
            border-radius: 8px 0 0 0;
        }

        /* Skins */
        .tabbed[class*="skin-"] ul li {
            color: #FFF;
            text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.1) 0 1px;
        }

        .tabbed.skin-turquoise {
            border-bottom-color: #1ABC9C;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-turquoise ul li,
        .tabbed.skin-turquoise ul li:before,
        .tabbed.skin-turquoise ul li:after {
            background-color: #34D6B6;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-turquoise ul li:hover,
        .tabbed.skin-turquoise ul li:hover:before,
        .tabbed.skin-turquoise ul li:hover:after {
            background-color: #40E2C2;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-turquoise ul li.active,
        .tabbed.skin-turquoise ul li.active:before,
        .tabbed.skin-turquoise ul li.active:after {
            background-color: #1ABC9C;
        }

        .tabbed.skin-emerald {
            border-bottom-color: #2ECC71;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-emerald ul li,
        .tabbed.skin-emerald ul li:before,
        .tabbed.skin-emerald ul li:after {
            background-color: #48E68B;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-emerald ul li:hover,
        .tabbed.skin-emerald ul li:hover:before,
        .tabbed.skin-emerald ul li:hover:after {
            background-color: #54F297;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-emerald ul li.active,
        .tabbed.skin-emerald ul li.active:before,
        .tabbed.skin-emerald ul li.active:after {
            background-color: #2ECC71;
        }

        .tabbed.skin-peter-river {
            border-bottom-color: #3498DB;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-peter-river ul li,
        .tabbed.skin-peter-river ul li:before,
        .tabbed.skin-peter-river ul li:after {
            background-color: #4EB2F5;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-peter-river ul li:hover,
        .tabbed.skin-peter-river ul li:hover:before,
        .tabbed.skin-peter-river ul li:hover:after {
            background-color: #5ABEFF;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-peter-river ul li.active,
        .tabbed.skin-peter-river ul li.active:before,
        .tabbed.skin-peter-river ul li.active:after {
            background-color: #3498DB;
        }

        .tabbed.skin-amethyst {
            border-bottom-color: #9B59B6;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-amethyst ul li,
        .tabbed.skin-amethyst ul li:before,
        .tabbed.skin-amethyst ul li:after {
            background-color: #B573D0;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-amethyst ul li:hover,
        .tabbed.skin-amethyst ul li:hover:before,
        .tabbed.skin-amethyst ul li:hover:after {
            background-color: #C17FDC;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-amethyst ul li.active,
        .tabbed.skin-amethyst ul li.active:before,
        .tabbed.skin-amethyst ul li.active:after {
            background-color: #9B59B6;
        }

        .tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt {
            border-bottom-color: #34495E;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt ul li,
        .tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt ul li:before,
        .tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt ul li:after {
            background-color: #4E6378;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt ul li:hover,
        .tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt ul li:hover:before,
        .tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt ul li:hover:after {
            background-color: #5A6F84;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt ul li.active,
        .tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt ul li.active:before,
        .tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt ul li.active:after {
            background-color: #34495E;
        }

        .tabbed.skin-sun-flower {
            border-bottom-color: #F1C40F;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-sun-flower ul li,
        .tabbed.skin-sun-flower ul li:before,
        .tabbed.skin-sun-flower ul li:after {
            background-color: #FFDE29;
            color: #0A0;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-sun-flower ul li:hover,
        .tabbed.skin-sun-flower ul li:hover:before,
        .tabbed.skin-sun-flower ul li:hover:after {
            background-color: #FFEA35;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-sun-flower ul li.active,
        .tabbed.skin-sun-flower ul li.active:before,
        .tabbed.skin-sun-flower ul li.active:after {
            background-color: #F1C40F;
            color: #FFF;
        }

        .tabbed.skin-carrot {
            border-bottom-color: #E67E22;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-carrot ul li,
        .tabbed.skin-carrot ul li:before,
        .tabbed.skin-carrot ul li:after {
            background-color: #FF983C;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-carrot ul li:hover,
        .tabbed.skin-carrot ul li:hover:before,
        .tabbed.skin-carrot ul li:hover:after {
            background-color: #FFA448;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-carrot ul li.active,
        .tabbed.skin-carrot ul li.active:before,
        .tabbed.skin-carrot ul li.active:after {
            background-color: #E67E22;
        }

        .tabbed.skin-alizarin {
            border-bottom-color: #E74C3C;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-alizarin ul li,
        .tabbed.skin-alizarin ul li:before,
        .tabbed.skin-alizarin ul li:after {
            background-color: #FF6656;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-alizarin ul li:hover,
        .tabbed.skin-alizarin ul li:hover:before,
        .tabbed.skin-alizarin ul li:hover:after {
            background-color: #FF7262;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-alizarin ul li.active,
        .tabbed.skin-alizarin ul li.active:before,
        .tabbed.skin-alizarin ul li.active:after {
            background-color: #E74C3C;
        }

        .tabbed.skin-graphite {
            border-bottom-color: #454545;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-graphite ul li,
        .tabbed.skin-graphite ul li:before,
        .tabbed.skin-graphite ul li:after {
            background-color: #5F5F5F;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-graphite ul li:hover,
        .tabbed.skin-graphite ul li:hover:before,
        .tabbed.skin-graphite ul li:hover:after {
            background-color: #6B6B6B;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-graphite ul li.active,
        .tabbed.skin-graphite ul li.active:before,
        .tabbed.skin-graphite ul li.active:after {
            background-color: #454545;
        }

        .tabbed.skin-concrete {
            border-bottom-color: #95A5A6;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-concrete ul li,
        .tabbed.skin-concrete ul li:before,
        .tabbed.skin-concrete ul li:after {
            background-color: #AFBFC0;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-concrete ul li:hover,
        .tabbed.skin-concrete ul li:hover:before,
        .tabbed.skin-concrete ul li:hover:after {
            background-color: #BBCBCC;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-concrete ul li.active,
        .tabbed.skin-concrete ul li.active:before,
        .tabbed.skin-concrete ul li.active:after {
            background-color: #95A5A6;
        }

        .tabbed.skin-green-sea {
            border-bottom-color: #16A085;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-green-sea ul li,
        .tabbed.skin-green-sea ul li:before,
        .tabbed.skin-green-sea ul li:after {
            background-color: #30BA9F;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-green-sea ul li:hover,
        .tabbed.skin-green-sea ul li:hover:before,
        .tabbed.skin-green-sea ul li:hover:after {
            background-color: #3CC6AB;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-green-sea ul li.active,
        .tabbed.skin-green-sea ul li.active:before,
        .tabbed.skin-green-sea ul li.active:after {
            background-color: #16A085;
        }

        .tabbed.skin-nephritis {
            border-bottom-color: #27AE60;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-nephritis ul li,
        .tabbed.skin-nephritis ul li:before,
        .tabbed.skin-nephritis ul li:after {
            background-color: #41C87A;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-nephritis ul li:hover,
        .tabbed.skin-nephritis ul li:hover:before,
        .tabbed.skin-nephritis ul li:hover:after {
            background-color: #4DD486;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-nephritis ul li.active,
        .tabbed.skin-nephritis ul li.active:before,
        .tabbed.skin-nephritis ul li.active:after {
            background-color: #27AE60;
        }

        .tabbed.skin-belize-hole {
            border-bottom-color: #2980B9;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-belize-hole ul li,
        .tabbed.skin-belize-hole ul li:before,
        .tabbed.skin-belize-hole ul li:after {
            background-color: #439AD3;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-belize-hole ul li:hover,
        .tabbed.skin-belize-hole ul li:hover:before,
        .tabbed.skin-belize-hole ul li:hover:after {
            background-color: #4FA6DF;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-belize-hole ul li.active,
        .tabbed.skin-belize-hole ul li.active:before,
        .tabbed.skin-belize-hole ul li.active:after {
            background-color: #2980B9;
        }

        .tabbed.skin-wisteria {
            border-bottom-color: #8E44AD;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-wisteria ul li,
        .tabbed.skin-wisteria ul li:before,
        .tabbed.skin-wisteria ul li:after {
            background-color: #A85EC7;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-wisteria ul li:hover,
        .tabbed.skin-wisteria ul li:hover:before,
        .tabbed.skin-wisteria ul li:hover:after {
            background-color: #B46AD3;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-wisteria ul li.active,
        .tabbed.skin-wisteria ul li.active:before,
        .tabbed.skin-wisteria ul li.active:after {
            background-color: #8E44AD;
        }

        .tabbed.skin-midnight-blue {
            border-bottom-color: #2C3E50;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-midnight-blue ul li,
        .tabbed.skin-midnight-blue ul li:before,
        .tabbed.skin-midnight-blue ul li:after {
            background-color: #46586A;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-midnight-blue ul li:hover,
        .tabbed.skin-midnight-blue ul li:hover:before,
        .tabbed.skin-midnight-blue ul li:hover:after {
            background-color: #526476;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-midnight-blue ul li.active,
        .tabbed.skin-midnight-blue ul li.active:before,
        .tabbed.skin-midnight-blue ul li.active:after {
            background-color: #2C3E50;
        }

        .tabbed.skin-orange {
            border-bottom-color: #F39C12;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-orange ul li,
        .tabbed.skin-orange ul li:before,
        .tabbed.skin-orange ul li:after {
            background-color: #FFB62C;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-orange ul li:hover,
        .tabbed.skin-orange ul li:hover:before,
        .tabbed.skin-orange ul li:hover:after {
            background-color: #FFC238;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-orange ul li.active,
        .tabbed.skin-orange ul li.active:before,
        .tabbed.skin-orange ul li.active:after {
            background-color: #F39C12;
        }

        .tabbed.skin-pumpkin {
            border-bottom-color: #D35400;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-pumpkin ul li,
        .tabbed.skin-pumpkin ul li:before,
        .tabbed.skin-pumpkin ul li:after {
            background-color: #ED6E1A;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-pumpkin ul li:hover,
        .tabbed.skin-pumpkin ul li:hover:before,
        .tabbed.skin-pumpkin ul li:hover:after {
            background-color: #F97A26;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-pumpkin ul li.active,
        .tabbed.skin-pumpkin ul li.active:before,
        .tabbed.skin-pumpkin ul li.active:after {
            background-color: #D35400;
        }

        .tabbed.skin-pomegranate {
            border-bottom-color: #C0392B;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-pomegranate ul li,
        .tabbed.skin-pomegranate ul li:before,
        .tabbed.skin-pomegranate ul li:after {
            background-color: #DA5345;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-pomegranate ul li:hover,
        .tabbed.skin-pomegranate ul li:hover:before,
        .tabbed.skin-pomegranate ul li:hover:after {
            background-color: #E65F51;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-pomegranate ul li.active,
        .tabbed.skin-pomegranate ul li.active:before,
        .tabbed.skin-pomegranate ul li.active:after {
            background-color: #C0392B;
        }

        .tabbed.skin-silver {
            border-bottom-color: #BDC3C7;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-silver ul li,
        .tabbed.skin-silver ul li:before,
        .tabbed.skin-silver ul li:after {
            background-color: #D7DDE1;
            color: #666;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-silver ul li:hover,
        .tabbed.skin-silver ul li:hover:before,
        .tabbed.skin-silver ul li:hover:after {
            background-color: #E3E9ED;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-silver ul li.active,
        .tabbed.skin-silver ul li.active:before,
        .tabbed.skin-silver ul li.active:after {
            background-color: #BDC3C7;
            color: #FFF;
        }

        .tabbed.skin-asbestos {
            border-bottom-color: #7F8C8D;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-asbestos ul li,
        .tabbed.skin-asbestos ul li:before,
        .tabbed.skin-asbestos ul li:after {
            background-color: #99A6A7;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-asbestos ul li:hover,
        .tabbed.skin-asbestos ul li:hover:before,
        .tabbed.skin-asbestos ul li:hover:after {
            background-color: #A5B2B3;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-asbestos ul li.active,
        .tabbed.skin-asbestos ul li.active:before,
        .tabbed.skin-asbestos ul li.active:after {
            background-color: #7F8C8D;
        }

        .tabbed.skin-dodgerblue {
            border-bottom-color: dodgerblue;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-dodgerblue ul li,
        .tabbed.skin-dodgerblue ul li:before,
        .tabbed.skin-dodgerblue ul li:after {
            background-color: deepskyblue;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-dodgerblue ul li:hover,
        .tabbed.skin-dodgerblue ul li:hover:before,
        .tabbed.skin-dodgerblue ul li:hover:after {
            background-color: #33ccff;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-dodgerblue ul li.active,
        .tabbed.skin-dodgerblue ul li.active:before,
        .tabbed.skin-dodgerblue ul li.active:after {
            background-color: dodgerblue;
        }

        .tabbed.skin-gray-black {
            border-bottom-color: #28343b;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-gray-black,
        .tabbed.skin-gray-black ul li,
        .tabbed.skin-gray-black ul li:before,
        .tabbed.skin-gray-black ul li:after {
            transition: none;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-gray-black ul li,
        .tabbed.skin-gray-black ul li:before,
        .tabbed.skin-gray-black ul li:after {
            background-color: #68737B;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-gray-black ul li:hover,
        .tabbed.skin-gray-black ul li:hover:before,
        .tabbed.skin-gray-black ul li:hover:after {
            background-color: #707A83;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-gray-black ul li.active,
        .tabbed.skin-gray-black ul li.active:before,
        .tabbed.skin-gray-black ul li.active:after {
            background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIwJSIgeTI9IjEwMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI2I1YmRjOCIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiMyODM0M2IiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPgogIDwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+CiAgPHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
        }

        .tabbed.skin-black-glass {
            border-bottom-color: #0a0809;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-black-glass,
        .tabbed.skin-black-glass ul li,
        .tabbed.skin-black-glass ul li:before,
        .tabbed.skin-black-glass ul li:after {
            transition: none;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-black-glass ul li,
        .tabbed.skin-black-glass ul li:before,
        .tabbed.skin-black-glass ul li:after {
            background-color: #333;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-black-glass ul li:hover,
        .tabbed.skin-black-glass ul li:hover:before,
        .tabbed.skin-black-glass ul li:hover:after {
            background-color: #444;
        }
        .tabbed.skin-black-glass ul li.active,
        .tabbed.skin-black-glass ul li.active:before,
        .tabbed.skin-black-glass ul li.active:after {
            background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIwJSIgeTI9IjEwMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI2FlYmNiZiIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjUwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzZlNzc3NCIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjUwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzBhMGUwYSIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiMwYTA4MDkiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPgogIDwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+CiAgPHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Amazing Tabs</h2>
    <div class="tabbed round">
        <ul>
            <li>Tab4</li>
            <li>Tab3</li>
            <li>Tab2</li>
            <li class="active">Tab1</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <br><br><br>



    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            var tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tabbed li');
            var switchers = document.querySelectorAll('.switcher-box a');
            var skinable = document.getElementById('skinable');

            for (var i = 0, len = tabs.length; i < len; i++) {
                tabs[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                    if (this.classList.contains('active'))
                        return;

                    var parent = this.parentNode,
                        innerTabs = parent.querySelectorAll('li');

                    for (var index = 0, iLen = innerTabs.length; index < iLen; index++) {
                        innerTabs[index].classList.remove('active');
                    }

                    this.classList.add('active');
                });
            }

            for (var i = 0, len = switchers.length; i < len; i++) {
                switchers[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                    if (this.classList.contains('active'))
                        return;

                    var parent = this.parentNode,
                        innerSwitchers = parent.querySelectorAll('a'),
                        skinName = this.getAttribute('skin');

                    for (var index = 0, iLen = innerSwitchers.length; index < iLen; index++) {
                        innerSwitchers[index].classList.remove('active');
                    }

                    this.classList.add('active');
                    skinable.className = 'tabbed round ' + skinName;
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

I want to be able to click on the tabs in the email itself but i don't know how to change the code from using JS for this responsability to using html/css only in order to be able to click on the tabs.

Comment: It doesn't look like the `:checked` pseudo-selector is supported in Thunderbird, which probably means there is no way to get a tabbed ui for Thunderbird.

Comment: There are ways for making tabbed ui in Thunderbird emails, for example, i tried the following code and it works: 
https://freshinbox.com/blog/interactive-tabs-for-email/

The thing is that I don't have experience in frontend development and i thought i would find in here some experienced frontend devs that would know how to adjust the code so it can run in Thunderbird also. 

Thanks a lot for your info!

Comment: Hmm the code there didn't work for me in Thunderbird. The tabs never responded on click.

Comment: I just verified again. I downloaded the code and save it in a .html file and i sent it with Thunderbird and the tabs in the received email worked.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. I thought you wanted the content of the email to be written in html. File attachments are basically a file. Why wouldn't javascript run in the browser?

Comment: I specified in the description that I'm trying to send a .html report with Thunderbird. The report is a .html file and i and my colleagues have 'Display Attachements Inline' Thunderbird option checked so, we don't need to download the .html file because we directly see it in Thunderbird.

Comment: I use Thunderbird client not browser.

Comment: Yeah me too. The code in the link just doesn't work for me. Clicking on the tabs there is no response. I did check that with the `Display Attachements Inline` on. Not sure how that is working for you.

Comment: Did you used the code from the Final Code section - HTML, from the bottom of the page? If so, I don't know why it doesn't work for you, maybe some Thunderbird options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have basically applied the same changes as specified in your comments. It makes use of `:checked` to get the selection effect and `form` to make the selections work.

I have modified the code. It does not make use of JavaScript anymore. It looks like it is working on ThunderBird.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Modern Tabs Design with pure CSS</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300, 400);

      html,
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background: #e8ecef;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
      }
      h1 {
        font: 400 30px roboto, "Open Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif;
        text-transform: uppercase;
      }
      h2 {
        font: 300 22px roboto, "Open Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif;
        text-transform: uppercase;
      }

      .myradio {
        display: none;
        height: 0px;
        visibility: hidden;
      }
      .switcher-box {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 40px 0;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .switcher-box a {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 32px;
        height: 32px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        padding: 3px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background: #fff;

        -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
        border-radius: 50%;

        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
        box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
      }
      .switcher-box a span {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;

        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset,
          0 5px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) inset;
        box-shadow: 0 -5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset,
          0 5px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) inset;

        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;

        -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
        border-radius: 50%;
      }
      .switcher-box a.active {
        background: #000;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
        box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
      }
      .switcher-box a.active span {
        border-color: #bbb;
      }

      .switcher-box a.skin-turquoise span {
        background: #1abc9c;
      }
      .switcher-box a.skin-emerald span {
        background: #2ecc71;
      }
      .switcher-box a.skin-peter-river span {
        background: #3498db;
      }
      .switcher-box a.skin-amethyst span {
        background: #9b59b6;
      }
      .switcher-box a.skin-wet-asphalt span {
        background: #34495e;
      }
      .switcher-box a.skin-sun-flower span {
        background: #f1c40f;
      }
      .switcher-box a.skin-carrot span {
        background: #e67e22;
      }
      .switcher-box a.skin-alizarin span {
        background: #e74c3c;
      }
      .switcher-box a.skin-graphite span {
        background: #454545;
      }
      .switcher-box a.skin-concrete span {
        background: #95a5a6;
      }
      .switcher-box a.skin-green-sea span {
        background: #16a085;
      }
      .switcher-box a.skin-nephritis span {
        background: #27ae60;
      }
      .switcher-box a.skin-belize-hole span {
        background: #2980b9;
      }
      .switcher-box a.skin-wisteria span {
        background: #8e44ad;
      }
      .switcher-box a.skin-midnight-blue span {
        background: #2c3e50;
      }
      .switcher-box a.skin-orange span {
        background: #f39c12;
      }
      .switcher-box a.skin-pumpkin span {
        background: #d35400;
      }
      .switcher-box a.skin-pomegranate span {
        background: #c0392b;
      }
      .switcher-box a.skin-silver span {
        background: #bdc3c7;
      }
      .switcher-box a.skin-asbestos span {
        background: #7f8c8d;
      }
      .switcher-box a.skin-dodgerblue span {
        background: dodgerblue;
      }
      .switcher-box a.skin-gray-black span {
        background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIwJSIgeTI9IjEwMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI2I1YmRjOCIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiMyODM0M2IiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPgogIDwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+CiAgPHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
      }
      .switcher-box a.skin-black-glass span {
        background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
      }

      .myradio:checked + label {
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      /* Tabbed Styles */
      .tabbed {
        width: 80%;
        min-width: 400px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-bottom: 68px;
        border-bottom: 4px solid #000;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: border 250ms ease;
      }
      .tabbed ul {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        float: left;
        padding-left: 48px;
        list-style-type: none;
      }
      .tabbed ul * {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
      .tabbed ul .myradio + label {
        display: block;
        float: right;
        padding: 10px 24px 8px;
        background-color: #fff;
        margin-right: 46px;
        z-index: 2;
        position: relative;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #777;

        text-transform: uppercase;
        font: 600 13px/20px roboto, "Open Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif;

        transition: all 250ms ease;
      }
      .tabbed ul .myradio + label:before,
      .tabbed ul .myradio + label:after {
        display: block;
        content: " ";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 44px;
        background-color: #fff;
        transition: all 250ms ease;
      }
      .tabbed ul .myradio + label:before {
        right: -24px;
        transform: skew(30deg, 0deg);
        box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 3px 2px 5px,
          inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.09) -1px 0;
      }
      .tabbed ul .myradio + label:after {
        left: -24px;
        transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
        box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) -3px 2px 5px,
          inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.09) 1px 0;
      }
      .tabbed ul .myradio + label:hover,
      .tabbed ul .myradio + label:hover:before,
      .tabbed ul .myradio + label:hover:after {
        background-color: #f4f7f9;
        color: #444;
      }
      .tabbed ul .myradio:checked + label {
        z-index: 3;
      }
      .tabbed ul .myradio:checked + label,
      .tabbed ul .myradio:checked + label:before,
      .tabbed ul .myradio:checked + label:after {
        background-color: #000;
        color: #fff;
      }

      /* Round Tabs */
      .tabbed.round ul .myradio + label {
        border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
      }
      .tabbed.round ul .myradio + label:before {
        border-radius: 0 8px 0 0;
      }
      .tabbed.round ul .myradio + label:after {
        border-radius: 8px 0 0 0;
      }

      /* Skins */
      .tabbed[class*="skin-"] ul .myradio + label {
        color: #fff;
        text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0 1px;
      }

      .tabbed.skin-turquoise {
        border-bottom-color: #1abc9c;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-turquoise ul .myradio + label,
      .tabbed.skin-turquoise ul .myradio + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-turquoise ul .myradio + label:after {
        background-color: #34d6b6;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-turquoise ul .myradio + label:hover,
      .tabbed.skin-turquoise ul .myradio + label:hover:before,
      .tabbed.skin-turquoise ul .myradio + label:hover:after {
        background-color: #40e2c2;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-turquoise ul .myradio:checked + label,
      .tabbed.skin-turquoise ul .myradio:checked + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-turquoise ul .myradio:checked + label:after {
        background-color: #1abc9c;
      }

      .tabbed.skin-emerald {
        border-bottom-color: #2ecc71;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-emerald ul .myradio + label,
      .tabbed.skin-emerald ul .myradio + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-emerald ul .myradio + label:after {
        background-color: #48e68b;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-emerald ul .myradio + label:hover,
      .tabbed.skin-emerald ul .myradio + label:hover:before,
      .tabbed.skin-emerald ul .myradio + label:hover:after {
        background-color: #54f297;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-emerald ul .myradio:checked + label,
      .tabbed.skin-emerald ul .myradio:checked + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-emerald ul .myradio:checked + label:after {
        background-color: #2ecc71;
      }

      .tabbed.skin-peter-river {
        border-bottom-color: #3498db;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-peter-river ul .myradio + label,
      .tabbed.skin-peter-river ul .myradio + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-peter-river ul .myradio + label:after {
        background-color: #4eb2f5;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-peter-river ul .myradio + label:hover,
      .tabbed.skin-peter-river ul .myradio + label:hover:before,
      .tabbed.skin-peter-river ul .myradio + label:hover:after {
        background-color: #5abeff;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-peter-river ul .myradio:checked + label,
      .tabbed.skin-peter-river ul .myradio:checked + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-peter-river ul .myradio:checked + label:after {
        background-color: #3498db;
      }

      .tabbed.skin-amethyst {
        border-bottom-color: #9b59b6;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-amethyst ul .myradio + label,
      .tabbed.skin-amethyst ul .myradio + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-amethyst ul .myradio + label:after {
        background-color: #b573d0;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-amethyst ul .myradio + label:hover,
      .tabbed.skin-amethyst ul .myradio + label:hover:before,
      .tabbed.skin-amethyst ul .myradio + label:hover:after {
        background-color: #c17fdc;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-amethyst ul .myradio:checked + label,
      .tabbed.skin-amethyst ul .myradio:checked + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-amethyst ul .myradio:checked + label:after {
        background-color: #9b59b6;
      }

      .tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt {
        border-bottom-color: #34495e;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt ul .myradio + label,
      .tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt ul .myradio + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt ul .myradio + label:after {
        background-color: #4e6378;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt ul .myradio + label:hover,
      .tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt ul .myradio + label:hover:before,
      .tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt ul .myradio + label:hover:after {
        background-color: #5a6f84;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt ul .myradio:checked + label,
      .tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt ul .myradio:checked + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-wet-asphalt ul .myradio:checked + label:after {
        background-color: #34495e;
      }

      .tabbed.skin-sun-flower {
        border-bottom-color: #f1c40f;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-sun-flower ul .myradio + label,
      .tabbed.skin-sun-flower ul .myradio + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-sun-flower ul .myradio + label:after {
        background-color: #ffde29;
        color: #0a0;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-sun-flower ul .myradio + label:hover,
      .tabbed.skin-sun-flower ul .myradio + label:hover:before,
      .tabbed.skin-sun-flower ul .myradio + label:hover:after {
        background-color: #ffea35;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-sun-flower ul .myradio:checked + label,
      .tabbed.skin-sun-flower ul .myradio:checked + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-sun-flower ul .myradio:checked + label:after {
        background-color: #f1c40f;
        color: #fff;
      }

      .tabbed.skin-carrot {
        border-bottom-color: #e67e22;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-carrot ul .myradio + label,
      .tabbed.skin-carrot ul .myradio + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-carrot ul .myradio + label:after {
        background-color: #ff983c;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-carrot ul .myradio + label:hover,
      .tabbed.skin-carrot ul .myradio + label:hover:before,
      .tabbed.skin-carrot ul .myradio + label:hover:after {
        background-color: #ffa448;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-carrot ul .myradio:checked + label,
      .tabbed.skin-carrot ul .myradio:checked + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-carrot ul .myradio:checked + label:after {
        background-color: #e67e22;
      }

      .tabbed.skin-alizarin {
        border-bottom-color: #e74c3c;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-alizarin ul .myradio + label,
      .tabbed.skin-alizarin ul .myradio + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-alizarin ul .myradio + label:after {
        background-color: #ff6656;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-alizarin ul .myradio + label:hover,
      .tabbed.skin-alizarin ul .myradio + label:hover:before,
      .tabbed.skin-alizarin ul .myradio + label:hover:after {
        background-color: #ff7262;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-alizarin ul .myradio:checked + label,
      .tabbed.skin-alizarin ul .myradio:checked + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-alizarin ul .myradio:checked + label:after {
        background-color: #e74c3c;
      }

      .tabbed.skin-graphite {
        border-bottom-color: #454545;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-graphite ul .myradio + label,
      .tabbed.skin-graphite ul .myradio + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-graphite ul .myradio + label:after {
        background-color: #5f5f5f;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-graphite ul .myradio + label:hover,
      .tabbed.skin-graphite ul .myradio + label:hover:before,
      .tabbed.skin-graphite ul .myradio + label:hover:after {
        background-color: #6b6b6b;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-graphite ul .myradio:checked + label,
      .tabbed.skin-graphite ul .myradio:checked + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-graphite ul .myradio:checked + label:after {
        background-color: #454545;
      }

      .tabbed.skin-concrete {
        border-bottom-color: #95a5a6;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-concrete ul .myradio + label,
      .tabbed.skin-concrete ul .myradio + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-concrete ul .myradio + label:after {
        background-color: #afbfc0;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-concrete ul .myradio + label:hover,
      .tabbed.skin-concrete ul .myradio + label:hover:before,
      .tabbed.skin-concrete ul .myradio + label:hover:after {
        background-color: #bbcbcc;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-concrete ul .myradio:checked + label,
      .tabbed.skin-concrete ul .myradio:checked + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-concrete ul .myradio:checked + label:after {
        background-color: #95a5a6;
      }

      .tabbed.skin-green-sea {
        border-bottom-color: #16a085;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-green-sea ul .myradio + label,
      .tabbed.skin-green-sea ul .myradio + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-green-sea ul .myradio + label:after {
        background-color: #30ba9f;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-green-sea ul .myradio + label:hover,
      .tabbed.skin-green-sea ul .myradio + label:hover:before,
      .tabbed.skin-green-sea ul .myradio + label:hover:after {
        background-color: #3cc6ab;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-green-sea ul .myradio:checked + label,
      .tabbed.skin-green-sea ul .myradio:checked + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-green-sea ul .myradio:checked + label:after {
        background-color: #16a085;
      }

      .tabbed.skin-nephritis {
        border-bottom-color: #27ae60;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-nephritis ul .myradio + label,
      .tabbed.skin-nephritis ul .myradio + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-nephritis ul .myradio + label:after {
        background-color: #41c87a;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-nephritis ul .myradio + label:hover,
      .tabbed.skin-nephritis ul .myradio + label:hover:before,
      .tabbed.skin-nephritis ul .myradio + label:hover:after {
        background-color: #4dd486;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-nephritis ul .myradio:checked + label,
      .tabbed.skin-nephritis ul .myradio:checked + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-nephritis ul .myradio:checked + label:after {
        background-color: #27ae60;
      }

      .tabbed.skin-belize-hole {
        border-bottom-color: #2980b9;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-belize-hole ul .myradio + label,
      .tabbed.skin-belize-hole ul .myradio + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-belize-hole ul .myradio + label:after {
        background-color: #439ad3;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-belize-hole ul .myradio + label:hover,
      .tabbed.skin-belize-hole ul .myradio + label:hover:before,
      .tabbed.skin-belize-hole ul .myradio + label:hover:after {
        background-color: #4fa6df;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-belize-hole ul .myradio:checked + label,
      .tabbed.skin-belize-hole ul .myradio:checked + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-belize-hole ul .myradio:checked + label:after {
        background-color: #2980b9;
      }

      .tabbed.skin-wisteria {
        border-bottom-color: #8e44ad;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-wisteria ul .myradio + label,
      .tabbed.skin-wisteria ul .myradio + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-wisteria ul .myradio + label:after {
        background-color: #a85ec7;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-wisteria ul .myradio + label:hover,
      .tabbed.skin-wisteria ul .myradio + label:hover:before,
      .tabbed.skin-wisteria ul .myradio + label:hover:after {
        background-color: #b46ad3;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-wisteria ul .myradio:checked + label,
      .tabbed.skin-wisteria ul .myradio:checked + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-wisteria ul .myradio:checked + label:after {
        background-color: #8e44ad;
      }

      .tabbed.skin-midnight-blue {
        border-bottom-color: #2c3e50;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-midnight-blue ul .myradio + label,
      .tabbed.skin-midnight-blue ul .myradio + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-midnight-blue ul .myradio + label:after {
        background-color: #46586a;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-midnight-blue ul .myradio + label:hover,
      .tabbed.skin-midnight-blue ul .myradio + label:hover:before,
      .tabbed.skin-midnight-blue ul .myradio + label:hover:after {
        background-color: #526476;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-midnight-blue ul .myradio:checked + label,
      .tabbed.skin-midnight-blue ul .myradio:checked + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-midnight-blue ul .myradio:checked + label:after {
        background-color: #2c3e50;
      }

      .tabbed.skin-orange {
        border-bottom-color: #f39c12;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-orange ul .myradio + label,
      .tabbed.skin-orange ul .myradio + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-orange ul .myradio + label:after {
        background-color: #ffb62c;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-orange ul .myradio + label:hover,
      .tabbed.skin-orange ul .myradio + label:hover:before,
      .tabbed.skin-orange ul .myradio + label:hover:after {
        background-color: #ffc238;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-orange ul .myradio:checked + label,
      .tabbed.skin-orange ul .myradio:checked + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-orange ul .myradio:checked + label:after {
        background-color: #f39c12;
      }

      .tabbed.skin-pumpkin {
        border-bottom-color: #d35400;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-pumpkin ul .myradio + label,
      .tabbed.skin-pumpkin ul .myradio + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-pumpkin ul .myradio + label:after {
        background-color: #ed6e1a;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-pumpkin ul .myradio + label:hover,
      .tabbed.skin-pumpkin ul .myradio + label:hover:before,
      .tabbed.skin-pumpkin ul .myradio + label:hover:after {
        background-color: #f97a26;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-pumpkin ul .myradio:checked + label,
      .tabbed.skin-pumpkin ul .myradio:checked + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-pumpkin ul .myradio:checked + label:after {
        background-color: #d35400;
      }

      .tabbed.skin-pomegranate {
        border-bottom-color: #c0392b;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-pomegranate ul .myradio + label,
      .tabbed.skin-pomegranate ul .myradio + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-pomegranate ul .myradio + label:after {
        background-color: #da5345;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-pomegranate ul .myradio + label:hover,
      .tabbed.skin-pomegranate ul .myradio + label:hover:before,
      .tabbed.skin-pomegranate ul .myradio + label:hover:after {
        background-color: #e65f51;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-pomegranate ul .myradio:checked + label,
      .tabbed.skin-pomegranate ul .myradio:checked + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-pomegranate ul .myradio:checked + label:after {
        background-color: #c0392b;
      }

      .tabbed.skin-silver {
        border-bottom-color: #bdc3c7;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-silver ul .myradio + label,
      .tabbed.skin-silver ul .myradio + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-silver ul .myradio + label:after {
        background-color: #d7dde1;
        color: #666;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-silver ul .myradio + label:hover,
      .tabbed.skin-silver ul .myradio + label:hover:before,
      .tabbed.skin-silver ul .myradio + label:hover:after {
        background-color: #e3e9ed;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-silver ul .myradio:checked + label,
      .tabbed.skin-silver ul .myradio:checked + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-silver ul .myradio:checked + label:after {
        background-color: #bdc3c7;
        color: #fff;
      }

      .tabbed.skin-asbestos {
        border-bottom-color: #7f8c8d;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-asbestos ul .myradio + label,
      .tabbed.skin-asbestos ul .myradio + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-asbestos ul .myradio + label:after {
        background-color: #99a6a7;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-asbestos ul .myradio + label:hover,
      .tabbed.skin-asbestos ul .myradio + label:hover:before,
      .tabbed.skin-asbestos ul .myradio + label:hover:after {
        background-color: #a5b2b3;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-asbestos ul .myradio:checked + label,
      .tabbed.skin-asbestos ul .myradio:checked + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-asbestos ul .myradio:checked + label:after {
        background-color: #7f8c8d;
      }

      .tabbed.skin-dodgerblue {
        border-bottom-color: dodgerblue;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-dodgerblue ul .myradio + label,
      .tabbed.skin-dodgerblue ul .myradio + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-dodgerblue ul .myradio + label:after {
        background-color: deepskyblue;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-dodgerblue ul .myradio + label:hover,
      .tabbed.skin-dodgerblue ul .myradio + label:hover:before,
      .tabbed.skin-dodgerblue ul .myradio + label:hover:after {
        background-color: #33ccff;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-dodgerblue ul .myradio:checked + label,
      .tabbed.skin-dodgerblue ul .myradio:checked + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-dodgerblue ul .myradio:checked + label:after {
        background-color: dodgerblue;
      }

      .tabbed.skin-gray-black {
        border-bottom-color: #28343b;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-gray-black,
      .tabbed.skin-gray-black ul .myradio + label,
      .tabbed.skin-gray-black ul .myradio + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-gray-black ul .myradio + label:after {
        transition: none;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-gray-black ul .myradio + label,
      .tabbed.skin-gray-black ul .myradio + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-gray-black ul .myradio + label:after {
        background-color: #68737b;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-gray-black ul .myradio + label:hover,
      .tabbed.skin-gray-black ul .myradio + label:hover:before,
      .tabbed.skin-gray-black ul .myradio + label:hover:after {
        background-color: #707a83;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-gray-black ul .myradio:checked + label,
      .tabbed.skin-gray-black ul .myradio:checked + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-gray-black ul .myradio:checked + label:after {
        background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
      }

      .tabbed.skin-black-glass {
        border-bottom-color: #0a0809;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-black-glass,
      .tabbed.skin-black-glass ul li,
      .tabbed.skin-black-glass ul li:before,
      .tabbed.skin-black-glass ul li:after {
        transition: none;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-black-glass ul li,
      .tabbed.skin-black-glass ul li:before,
      .tabbed.skin-black-glass ul li:after {
        background-color: #333;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-black-glass ul .myradio + label:hover,
      .tabbed.skin-black-glass ul .myradio + label:hover:before,
      .tabbed.skin-black-glass ul .myradio + label:hover:after {
        background-color: #444;
      }
      .tabbed.skin-black-glass ul .myradio:checked + label,
      .tabbed.skin-black-glass ul .myradio:checked + label:before,
      .tabbed.skin-black-glass ul .myradio:checked + label:after {
        background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIwJSIgeTI9IjEwMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI2FlYmNiZiIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjUwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzZlNzc3NCIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjUwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzBhMGUwYSIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiMwYTA4MDkiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPgogIDwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+CiAgPHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h2>Amazing Tabs</h2>
    <div class="tabbed round">
      <ul>
        <form action="#">
          <input
            name="myradio"
            type="radio"
            id="radio1"
            class="myradio"
            checked
          />
          <label for="radio1">Tab 1</label>
          <input name="myradio" type="radio" id="radio2" class="myradio" />
          <label for="radio2">Tab 2</label>
        </form>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <br /><br /><br />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Indeed it works!!! Thanks a lot man, you've been of great help! I'll look carefully at the changes so i can learn something from this :).

Comment: And one more thing, I'm trying to add content for every tab isolated from each other. I' trying this for some hours now but I have no success. Do you mind if I ask again how can I do this?